# How can I achieve the following pattern using the DateTimeFormatter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, pattern-matching

I am looking to get the following format for a custom Header in my Rest Template "Wed, 10 Sep 2019 21:11:11 GMT", how can I amend the below to achieve this? Its currently throwing an `IllegallArgumentException`saying too many pattern letters.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddd, DD MMM YYYY, h:mm:ss ZZ");
String formatDateTime = LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter);
request.getHeaders().set("Date", formatDateTime);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few errors with the formatter

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E, dd MMM YYYY, hh:mm:ss ZZ");
    String formatDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now().format(formatter);

    System.out.println(formatDateTime);
```

Also `LocalDateTime` is a date-time without a time-zone.  use `ZonedDateTime`

Comment: If I wanted to replace the +0000 with GMT instead how would I do that? I tried ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("GMT") but still got +0000